# Sum all numeric columns in database and log results

Tags: sql, postgresql, logging

I have a query which gives me all numeric columns in my Postgres database:

```
SELECT table_schema, table_name, column_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema in (
'datawarehouse_x',
'datawarehouse_y',
'datawarehouse_z',
'datawarehouse_w'
)
and udt_name not in
('date','timestamp','bool','varchar')
and column_name not like '%_id'
```

This gives me, what I need:

```
table_schema   table_name   column_name      
schema_1       table_x      column_z
schema_2       table_y      column_w
```

I checked it and it's fine.
What I do now want to do is, to query all these columns for each table as a `select sum(column)` and then insert this schema_name, table_name, query_result and the current date into a log table on a daily basis.
Writing the results into a target table shouldn't be a big deal, but how in the world can I run queries according to the results of this query?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: What I will write afterwards would be a procedure, which takes these schema/table/column as input, then queries the table and writes into the log-table. I just do not know the part in-between. This is kind of what I would be doing then, but I don't know yet which types I should use for schema, table and column.

```
create or replace function sandbox.daily_routine_metrics(schema_name regnamespace, table_name regclass, column_name varchar)
  returns void
language plpgsql
as $$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE
        'INSERT INTO LOGGING.DAILY_ROUTINE_SIZE
        SELECT
        '|| QUOTE_LITERAL(schema_name) ||' schema_name,' ||
        QUOTE_LITERAL(table_name) ||' table_name, ' ||
        QUOTE_LITERAL(column_name) ||' column_name, ' ||
        'current_timestamp, sum(' || QUOTE_LITERAL(column_name) || ')
        FROM ' || QUOTE_LITERAL(schema_name) ||'.'|| QUOTE_LITERAL(table_name);
END;
$$;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature you need is known as "dynamic SQL". It's an RDBMS-specific implementation; the documents for Postgres are [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/ecpg-dynamic.html).

Whilst it's possible to achieve what you want in dynamic SQL, you might find it easier to use a scripting language like Python or Ruby to achieve this. Dynamic SQL is hard to code and debug - you find yourself concatenating lots of hardcoded strings with results from SQL queries, printing them to the console to see if they work, and realizing all sorts of edge cases blow up.

Comment: Hi Neville, thanks a lot for your response. Indeed, there is already a solution in R which I can think of. Unfortunately, my colleagues wish to have a SQL solution which they can change on their own. But with your answer in mind, perhaps there is a chance I can convince them. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnnyBanana looks like you'll accept as an answer to thank him.